# I tried to buy token with DAI. Its approved but I didnt receive any coin. Help please

Tags: uniswap, swaps, pancakeswap

It says that:
Transaction Action:
ApprovedDAIFor Trade OnUniswap V2: Router 2

Here is the transaction on etherscan: 0x181630a7d1ffaa58588eb6c5500d7f8529ca477621559eaf4a7587729e7ad45a

Why It didnt swap the coins but take the gas fee?
I didnt understand what is approved then?

Answer (score 1):

> I didnt understand what is approved then?

You must first run the `approve()` transaction to allow the Uniswap contracts to withdraw from your token balance on your behalf. (See the `approve()` part of the [ERC-20 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20).)

Once the approval has happened successfully, then the swap can occur in a different transaction. The approve and swap are two different transactions.

Comment: One more question why the gas fee increasing ever I try? The first try was like a hundred but now when I try to see how much the gas fee its almost 300

Comment: Good question. Gas prices are a market, and that market can go up or down. When the network has a lot of traffic, there is competition to get transactions into the next block. People are willing to pay more to get their transaction into a block quickly, so the gas prices increase. When there is less traffic - fewer people submitting transactions - then the gas prices go down.

Comment: You are such a wise man. Thanks a lot for illuminating me. Now I can see :)